# Phalcon hasFiles() always return true

Tags: php, file-upload, phalcon

file upload function is always returning `true` when checking `if` condition as `if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true)`; even if didn't upload any file.

**When the form is empty getting message as:**

> File format not supported

**Note:** *But working fine when image is uploaded.*

`HTML` form is created using `Phalcon tag`. Below is the function from `controller` and using `volt` to display `form`.

**Controller:**

```
function imageupload()
{
    if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true)
    {
        $upload_dir = BASE_PATH . '/files/';
        foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file) {
            if($file->getSize()>1000000)
            {
                $this->flash->error("File too big");
                return  false;
            }
            if(!in_array($file->getRealType(),array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif')))
            {
                $this->flash->error("File format not supported");
                return  false;
            }
            if($file->isUploadedFile())
            {
                $filename=rand().'_'.date('Ymdhis').'.'.$file->getExtension();
                $file->moveTo($upload_dir . $filename);
                return $filename;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->flash->error($file->getError());
                return  false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**View:**

```
        <?php
    echo $this->tag->form(['company/create','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']);
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <?php echo $this->tag->textField("name"); ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="logo">Logo</label>
        <?php echo $this->tag->fileField("logo"); ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
        <?php echo $this->tag->submitButton("Create"); ?>
    </p>
    <?php $this->tag->endForm(); ?>
```

**Call upload function:**

```
<?php
    $logoname=$this->imageupload();
    if($logoname==false)
    {
        $this->dispatcher->forward(['action' => 'new']);
    }
    else
    {   
        ......
        ....
        $success = $form->save();
        if($success)
        {
            $this->flash->success("Company successfully saved!");
            $this->dispatcher->forward(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->flash->error("Following Errors occured:");
            foreach($company->getMessages() as $message)
            {
                $this->flash->error($message);
            }
            $this->dispatcher->forward(['action' => 'new']);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you're getting as far as that error message, then `$file->getRealType()` must be running against an actual object, which means `getUploadedFiles()` is returning something. Time to start debugging.

Comment: @iainn my expection is if files is not uploaded then `if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true)` should return false. is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't know how Phalcon works specifically, but your expectation sounds correct. `$this->request->getUploadedFiles()` must be returning an array of objects if your code is behaving like that though, so start by seeing what it's returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by modifying `if` condition as below works as expected:

```
if ($this->request->hasFiles(true) == true)
```